# use of where(), orderBy() after mergeBinding() in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

Can you teach what is the proper way to create query builder in L5.3 
I have a code that something like this

**$query1** and **$query2** is both using DB::raw();

`$res = $query1->union($query2);
$querySql = $res->toSql();
$all_content_query = DB::table(DB::raw("($querySql) as a"))->mergeBindings($res)->whereIn('id', [1,2,3])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get()`

This set of code working in laravel 4.2 but now not working in laravel 5.4.
when I'm trying to remove the **where()** and **orderBy()** after mergeBinding I am getting record.

Maybe there is a proper way to do it?

Note that i don't want the where() to be put in any of the variables before add it to union. I want my query to be read as one.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with Laravel 5.3 but added the where clause before merge binding:

```
$memo = DB::table('communications')->select('subject,sender,recipients,cc,bcc,approval_list,communications.created_at,communications.type as message_type,communications.reftag,users.name as sender_name,users.photo,users.core_role as sender_role,users.reftag as sender_tag')->join('users','users.id','=','communications.sender')
    ->where('communications.type',1)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(1);

$queries = DB::table('communications')->select('subject,sender,recipients,cc,bcc,approval_list,communications.created_at,communications.type as message_type,communications.reftag,users.name as sender_name,users.photo,users.core_role as sender_role,users.reftag as sender_tag')->join('users','users.id','=','communications.sender')
    ->where('communications.type',2)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(1); 

$circular = DB::table('communications')->select('subject,sender,recipients,cc,bcc,approval_list,communications.created_at,communications.type as message_type,communications.reftag,users.name as sender_name,users.photo,users.core_role as sender_role,users.reftag as sender_tag')->join('users','users.id','=','communications.sender')
    ->where('communications.type',3)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->limit(1);

$sql = $memo->union($queries)->union($circular);
```

Since you are using db raw before merge bindings, write your where conditions there before the merge binding method. Worked for me:

```
$messages = DB::table('communications')->select('*')
->from(DB::raw("(".$sql->toSql().") as messages where (sender = ".$currentUser." or find_in_set(".$currentUser.", recipients) or find_in_set(".$currentUser.", cc) or find_in_set(".$currentUser.", bcc) or find_in_set(".$currentUser.", approval_list)) "))
->mergeBindings($sql->getQuery())->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```